# gridview SelectedDataKey - do I use this right?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I try to get the Social security number (SSN) of the selected element from a gridview when the user selects a row.

```
                <asp:GridView ID="PeopleGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
                ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
                onselectedindexchanged="GetDataForPerson" DataKeyNames="SSN">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
```

```
               <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" ButtonType="Button" SelectText="Select" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="NameHeader" DataField="NameProp" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="AddressHeader" DataField="PersAddressProp" />
               </Columns>

protected void GetDataForPerson(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var x= PeopleGrid.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString()  

   }
```

x should be the SSN of the selected person, but PeopleGrid.SelectedDataKey is null. What is wrong here?

This is how I bind the data:

```
PeopleGrid.DataSource = PeopleCollection;
            PeopleGrid.DataBind();
```

PeopleCollection is a collection of People.
Class people contains SSN, NameProp,  PersAddressProp

Comment: Please comment if my answer help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to find selected row "SSN" value then you need to use Gridview's DataKeys property, like GridView1.DataKeys["your_SelectedDataKey_index"]["your_selected_row_index"]. This is a read only property.

Comment: PeopleGrid.SelectedDataKey[0]; - this throws exception. SelectedDataKey is null so I can not add index

Comment: is there a column "SSN" in your datasource ? How you have bound your GridView?

Comment: I've added some code. Hope It's clear what I try to do. PeopleGrid.DataKeys is empty, so I can't use that index.

Comment: first you need to bind DataKeysName proprty, like GriedView1.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "SSN" }; and then to read int ssn = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value); This is like a example only.

Comment: Do like this in your case >>>>>  PeopleGrid.DataSource = PeopleCollection;  PeopleGrid.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "SSN" };  PeopleGrid.DataBind();

Comment: Still not working. I am creating a dictionary with rowNumber->SSN, then extract the SSN based on RowIndex. Is this ok?

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. I did a beginner mistake in not counting some page init code which was overriding the grid, thus it was empty. The code from the comments works very well and I've also set enableviewstate for grid to false for performance and is still working ery well. Thanks again!